# how to prevent button inner span tag unclickable or unresponsive when button clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with a button I have created, basically when I click the button it appears to be very unresponsive only firing about 50% of the time. At the moment I have a span tag inside the button and I think that maybe this is having an effect on the button click. Would this be right and if so what would be the best way to prevent the span being clicked?

**Button markup:**

```
<button class="btn view-newest btn-inverse is-active">
 <i class="icon icon-star"></i>
 <span>Click the button</span>
</button>
```

What I then have is a simple .on click event?

Comment: You don't need to prevent the span being clicked, just listen for all click events on the button.

Comment: hey, how do i listen for all the clicked events on the button?

Comment: jQuery(button).click(function(){do something..});

Comment: hey yeah thats what im currently doing

Comment: I have used similar buttons and didn't have any issues... can you make a jsfiddle which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `<span>` tag shouldn't be interfering with the jQuery click event listener if this is all the code you've got; it doesn't do anything fancy.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1exwbsx/) demonstrating this:

```
<button class="btn view-newest btn-inverse is-active">
 <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
 <span>Click the button</span>
</button>

<div id="timesClicked">Times clicked: </div>

<script>
    clicked = 0;
    $(".btn").on('click', function() {
        clicked++;
        $("#timesClicked").text("Times clicked: " + clicked)
   });
</script>
```

I'd check the console for errors, make sure that there's only one event listener and that it's being called in the right place, and check to see if there's any loose Javascript or CSS rules affecting the button.